# When i am trying to run the xml file, browser show me the message Error loading stylesheet: Failure analysis XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

As i described in the title above i have no clue what is wrong and why the browser (firefox, IE) show me this message (Error loading stylesheet: Failure analysis XSLT stylesheet). I will post below the xml file and the xsl file.

exam.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="exam.xsl"?>
<Exam>
    <Title>XML_Master_Exam</Title>
    <Information>
        <ExamName ExamNumber="I10-001">XML Master:Basic</ExamName>
        <ExamTime>60_Minutes</ExamTime>
        <Qeustions>50</Qeustions>
        <MinimumPass>at_least_70% correct</MinimumPass>
    </Information>
    <Information>
        <ExamName ExamNumber="I10-002">XML Master:Professional</ExamName>
        <ExamTime>90_Minutes</ExamTime>
        <Qeustions>40</Qeustions>
        <MinimumPass>at_least_60% correct</MinimumPass>
    </Information>
</Exam>
```

exam.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLTransform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <test_info>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//MinimumPass"/>
    </test_info>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MinimumPass">
    <test_no>
        <xsl:value-of select="../ExamName/@ExamNumber"/>
    </test_no>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the wrong namespace for `xsl`. You need to use `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <test_info>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//MinimumPass"/>
    </test_info>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MinimumPass">
    <test_no>
        <xsl:value-of select="../ExamName/@ExamNumber"/>
    </test_no>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: It is allowed to use `xsl:transform` as the root element. Your correction of the namespace is correct however.

Comment: Thank you both for pointing this out! Never knew that. Edited the answer.

Comment: Yes xsl:transform is the same as xsl:stylesheet, the problem was the namespace. Anyway i will accept your answer because it actually solve the problem.